# https request from java app to server with valid certification

Tags: java, security, ssl

I"m posting from a Java application to an https server, which is certified officialy. I have tried many different ways to solve the problem outlined in this post, but I'm still getting errors. The idea is that in the post request:

```
 *HttpsURLConnection con;
 URL url = new URL(requestURL+urlParams);
 con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 con.setSSLSocketFactory(getSocketFactoryFromPEM(pemPath));
 con.setRequestMethod("POST");*
```

Above I use an ssl socket, where I initialize a keystore. But I am not sure about the keystore creation. Do I need the cert and the key of the server? And is there something more that should be done from server side? So far I am creating the keystore like that:

```
 *keystore.setKeyEntry("key-alias", privateKey, "changeit".toCharArray(), 
 new Certificate[] {cert});*
```

Where the private key is generated client side and cert is the server cert.

If somebody can give me a suggestion it will be really helpful.

Comment: do you need to create a keystore ?? i think you can send your post request without the need of initializing keystore and setting SSLSocketFactory, does the server need a client certificate ??

Comment: i set an ssl factory, for initializing it i need the keystore. Is it possible wihtout a keystore?

Comment: Why do you need a SSLSocketFactory()? HttpsURLConnection should work out of the box calling a https-URL.

Comment: that's what i thought, but i was getting an exception because of not valid handshake.

Comment: the actual exception is : Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(ClientHandshaker.java:1292)